# Find $\left | \left | \mathbf{u}-\mathbf{kv} \right | \right | $

Tags: linear-algebra

Find $\left | \left | \mathbf{u}-\mathbf{kv} \right | \right | $ in $\mathbb{R^2}$ with the weighted euclidean inner product $<\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}>=2u_1v_1+3u_2v_2$

$\mathbf{u}=(1,1)$, $k=3$ and $\mathbf{v}=(3,2)$

My attempt: It seems to me like there's 2 possible answers for what $k\mathbf{v}$ is, i.e. $k\mathbf{v}=(9,2)$ and $k\mathbf{v}=(3,6)$ so if I set $\mathbf{f}=\mathbf{u}-k\mathbf{v}$ I get $\mathbf{f}=(-8,-1)=(-2,-5)$ but this clearly isn't correct so then I of course get the wrong answer when calculating the distance. Can someone tell me what exactly I'm doing incorrectly here?

Comment: Why should $kv$ be $(3,6)$?

Comment: The dot product has been defined with constants in my book as satisfying the following condition. $<kv,u>=k<v,u>$ so I assumed it would make sense that it also satisfies the condition $k<v,u>=<v,ku>$

Comment: I do not understand why you have to define $kv$ differently to satisfy $<kv,u>=<v,ku>$? The inner product itself is defined to take care of this condition, which you can easily check.

Comment: Yea I agree that the definition holds because the inner product is defined to take care of that condition but I don't understand then how I am getting different vectors for $u-kv$. Also the vector I should be getting is $(-8,-5)$ which is oddly enough the first component of the first vector and the 2nd component of the second vector I listed above in my question.

Comment: I think you are confusing the inner product concept with the concept of finding $kv$. Note that inner product is a real number whereas, the product $kv$ is a *scalar multiple of  a vector* which gives you another vector. These two things are entirely separate. Also you won't be getting $(-8,-5)$ for $u-kv$, instead it will be $(-8,-1)$.

Comment: Ah thanks so much I understand now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the weighted inner product as $$\langle x,y\rangle=x^TWy$$ where $$W=\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0\\
0 & 3
\end{bmatrix}$$ Thus, $$\|u-kv\|^2=(u-kv)^TW(u-kv)$$ This would eliminate any possibility for error other than numerical one.

Answer (score 1):

Well first off, a norm is a function that maps items from your vector space into elements of $\mathbb{R}$. So the norm $\Vert \mathbf{u}-k\mathbf{v}\Vert$ will give you a number, not a vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Using the $\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v}$ and $k$ you described, we have

$$
\mathbf{u}-k\mathbf{v}=(1,1)-3(3,2)=(1,1)-(3\cdot 3,3\cdot 2)=(1,1)-(9,6)=(-8,-5).
$$
Recall the identity
$$
\Vert x \Vert^2 = \langle x,x\rangle,
$$
which relates norms and inner products. It follows that
$$
\Vert\mathbf{u}-k\mathbf{v} \Vert^2=\langle\mathbf{u}-k\mathbf{v},\mathbf{u}-k\mathbf{v}\rangle=\langle(-8,-5),(-8,-5) \rangle.
$$
Now, using the inner product $\langle \mathbf{u},\mathbf{v} \rangle=2u_1v_1+3u_2v_2$,
$$
\Vert\mathbf{u}-k\mathbf{v} \Vert^2=\langle(-8,-5),(-8,-5) \rangle=2(-8)(-8)+3(-5)(-5)=128+75=203.
$$
Lastly, taking roots on both sides,
$$
\Vert\mathbf{u}-k\mathbf{v} \Vert=\sqrt{203}.
$$

Comment: This is also the result I obtained but it's supposedly equal to 203 according to my textbook.

Comment: @Craig I have updated my answer. It is because $k(a,b)=(ka,kb)$ for any vector $(a,b)$ and scalar $k$. Think about how the vector stretches/shrinks as a scalar is multiplied to it. Both the $x$ and $y$ coordinates change correspondingly.

Comment: @Craig for vectors we have $k(a,b)=(ka,kb)$, however for inner products, we have $k\langle a,b \rangle=\langle ka,b\rangle$.